# Where to place custom made ansible.cfg file?

Tags: ansible, yaml, config

The Ansible documentation about [precedence rules and configurations settings](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/general_precedence.html#configuration-settings) mentions that configuration file will be searched for in the following order:

- `ANSIBLE_CONFIG` (environment variable if set)
- `ansible.cfg` (in the current directory)
- `~/.ansible.cfg` (in the home directory)
- `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`

For the second option, what does current directory mean:

1. Is it the directory where the playbook is placed? In that case will all the roles imported inside this playbook able to use the settings mentioned in the `.cfg` file.
2. Is it the directory from where we run the command `ansible-playbook example.yml`?

Comment: By experience, I can answer is the option 2

Comment: @YLR if that is the case how should I set the value of library configuration to set the path for module search. Should I use path which is relative to ansible.cfg directory ?

Comment: Right, @YLR, I can confirm that too, it is the directory from where we run the command.

Answer (score 3):

you can look at the default ansible config that is being loaded using below.

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.9.27
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/admin/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.10.2 (main, Jan 17 2022, 00:00:00) [GCC 11.2.1 20211203 (Red Hat 11.2.1-7)]
```

But if you want to use a custom configuration and you want to use the second option of preparing the ansible.cfg you can place it any directory from where you will be running the ansible-playbook and other commands and it will try to load the settings from this current directory.

One way to check if your setting are actually getting detected and loaded from the current directory is by using below

```
$ ansible-config view
```

Comment: I want to use a custom config, so where should I place it,1. In the directory where playbook is present or 2. In the directory from where we run ansible-playbook command?

Comment: its 2 - in the directory from where we run ansible-playbook command

Comment: @ashishpm you can easily create a default ansible config file with all options commented out in the current directory with the following command: `ansible-config init -t all --disabled > ansible.cfg`. Please note that this will discard a pre-existing `ansible.cfg` file if it existed so use an other name in the command or mv the existing file prior to running the command.

Answer (score 1):

We generally have ansible.cfg in the git of the project. The reason is that every custom ansible.cfg (beyond enabling/disabling cowsay) has a reason. A custom library path, changes in variable precedence, etc, etc. Some of them are subtle and are not obvious when breaks.

Therefore, ansible.cfg is associated with playbooks, and is kept in the same git as playbooks.

Moreover we even has an assertion to check if 'our' ansible.cfg is in use:

ansible.cfg:

```
[tags]
SKIP=never, set_to_skip_in_ansible_cfg
```

_asserts.yaml:

```
---
- hosts: localhost, all
  run_once: true
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Check if proper ansible.cfg is used
      fail:
        msg: 'You should use ansible.cfg from this repository'
      tags: [set_to_skip_in_ansible_cfg]
```

(https://medium.com/opsops/how-to-assert-that-playbook-is-run-with-a-proper-ansible-cfg-712ce9c89479)